# How to track sent messages (SMS) in android?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, message, android-broadcast

I am developing an Android application which has one of it's features as to detect any messages (SMS) sent by an app to any number. For this I want to keep track of sent messages. I want to check the message as and when it is sent. I know there is a Broadcast Receiver for SMS Recieved which will automatically call the function when a message is received. Is there any method to do that for SMS Sent? I just need a technique to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a ContentObserver

```
public class InboxContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

    ContentResolver cr;
    Context ctxt;

    public InboxContentObserver(Handler handler, Context ctxt) {
        super(handler);
        this.cr = ctxt.getContentResolver();
        this.ctxt = ctxt;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting sms sync.");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               Cursor sms_sent_cursor = cr.query(Uri
                        .parse("content://sms"), null, "date > ?",
                new String[]{LAST_SYNC_TIME}, "_id asc");
                //....write your code here

            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Replace LAST_SYNC_TIME with the time.

Register the ContentObserver

```
new InboxContentObserver(new Handler(), getApplicationContext());
        getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"), true, inboxContentObserver);
```